# Printer - not allow going in sleeping mode

Tags: printing, hp

I have a "HP LaserJet P1102w" printer. I have "installed" it by installing the `foo2zjs` driver from http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/ by adding a PPD-File (Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2) in CUPS installation menu. It works fine. But in ca. 15 minutes after I switch the printer on (and don't use in this time) the printer goes in sleeping mode. After that I cann't print unless I restart the printer. How can I prevent this (going in sleeping mode)?

I just don't want to install the *hplipopensource* driver because it is to big. I search solution with `foo2zjs` driver.

Comment: There's no solution even with the official HPLIP, let alone with third-party obscure drivers. Your best bet is to install it in Windows and from the Windows driver disable the "auto off" feature. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I have tryed with Windows. It has an option "1 hour", but after checking this the printer (in Linux) go to sleep in ca. 0,5 hours. I have don't explore deeper.